# Auto Set WP Image controls height and width based on the databound Source

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I have a WP application in which I want to display a list of images that are databound to an observablecollection that is populated from a web service. I want the list of images to show-up with the same height and width from where they are retrieved. So, how do I get the image control to adjust its height and width automatically to the databound source.

Using the following code, the image doesn't show-up.

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image Source="{Binding AlbumPicture}" Stretch="Fill" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid>
```

The following works, but the height and width are different for each image. so, they don't look good.

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image Source="{Binding AlbumPicture}" Stretch="Fill" Width="200" Height="120"/>
  </Grid>
```

I tried the following and they haven't worked.

- set the Stretch="None"
- Databind Image controls Height, Width properties to those of the
  image using the following and the height and width are always 0.

  ```
   BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(updatedAlbum.AlbumPicture, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
   album.AlbumHeight = bmp.PixelHeight;
   album.AlbumWidth = bmp.PixelWidth;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work only after the image is loaded.

```
 album.AlbumHeight = bmp.PixelHeight;
 album.AlbumWidth = bmp.PixelWidth;
```

You need just wait for it, and then bind(or set directly) this values to your image control.

For example you can use method

```
<Image x:Name="img" ImageOpened="Img_OnImageOpened"/>

private void Img_OnImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //start from here to set width and height.
    //you can do it directly, or by the Binding
}
```